# give response a type of fetch response in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this in my list.json

```
[{"id": "1", "qty": 1}]
```

I call it via fetch

```
async function fetchPlaces() {
  let response = await fetch(`./data/list.json`);
  response = await response.json();
}
```

how can make the response same type as the interface?

```
IList {
   id: string,
   qty: number
}
```

I tried `response = await response.json() as IList[]` it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are reusing the `response` variable, which is inferred to be of type `Response` (which is what `fetch` returns)

The following works:

```
interface IList {
   id: string,
   qty: number
}

async function fetchPlaces() {
  let response = await fetch(`./data/list.json`);
  let decoded = await response.json() as IList[]; // type is IList[]
}
```